# Can we install deepin file manager on ubuntu or linux mint

Tags: filemanager

Recently I have found deepin os . To be honest I like the design of it , but I don't want to leave ubuntu . I have googled online 'how to get deepin file manager in ubuntu' , every time I get 'how to get deepin environment in ubutu' .. Is there any way to get only deepin filemanager in ubuntu ..

Comment: You haven't provided product or release details (*but do mention an off-topic OS in your title so are you on the correct site*?)  as I see it available for some releases via PPA/persaonl package archive.

Comment: You might want to consider asking your question on [their](https://bbs.deepin.org/en) forums for additional help...

Answer (score 3):

You can [install from source](https://github.com/linuxdeepin/dde-file-manager),

or use the `ubuntudde-dev/stable` ppa

```bsh
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntudde-dev/stable
sudo apt install dde-file-manager deepin-icon-theme
```

However, I see some minor graphical issues.

---

Remove with `ppa-purge`:

```bsh
sudo apt install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntudde-dev/stable
```